# Questions about geth for mining pool

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools

I have a few questions to ask about setting up a mining pool

1) Will there be an issue if I set up two geth instances with the same coin base?
Here it is not about private nodes, I am trying to do a fail over for geth, have at least two nodes running at the same time. I want to give them the same coin base, so I am a bit worried it will have some issue. like conflicts.

2)Do I need to connect as peers for the two geth instances?
Do I need to manually connect these two instances as peers?

3)Is it same if I keep mining with 2 geth instances or just one?
If I have two regional services, e.g. one at US, and one at Russia. Is it same if I have own regional geth instances to mine separately, or I have to point one regional pool to another region geth instance to force them mining on the same geth instance.

Comment: What pool operator do you use?

Comment: What do you mean pool operator?  I coded my own pool.